# Last is not a member of String() - VB.Net getting last word of string

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, string, split

I'm trying to get the last word of a string. I split the string by spaces, and then get Last, but it's showing an error "Last is not a member of String()"

```
str = "This is a string of words"
str = currentPriceString.Split(" ").Last
```

What am I doing wrong?

note: I do have a System.Linq reference

Comment: Are we to assume `currentPriceString` is the same string as `str`?  Always post the real code.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned the assembly reference, but seems that you missed to specify the import at the top of the class/module that contains that unit of code you shown.

```
Imports System.Linq
```

If you also have the import, then probably what happens is that you are targeting a .NetFx version lower than v3.5, where doesn't not exist **LINQ** features, check your .Net Framework targetting and increase it up to v3.5 or greater.

Comment: "where doesn't not exist LINQ features" -> "which does not have LINQ"?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = "This is a string of words"
Dim getLastWord As String = Mid(str, str.LastIndexOf(" ") + 2)
```

This will achieve getting any Characters past the last {space} in the String.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the`IEnumerable.Last(Of TSource)` extension method, your project must target .NET 3.5 or higher.

Please see the code example below:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

' The imports below are only required if the namespace(s)  
' have not been imported into your project's settings
Imports System.Linq ' Requires .NET 3.5 or higher
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic ' This is required to use the Visual Basic functions like Mid(), InStr(), MsgBox(), etc...

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str As String = "This is a string of words"
        Dim delim As Char = " "c
        Dim strArr As String() = str.Split(delim)
        Dim lastWord As String

        ' Requires the Microsoft Visual Basic namespace to be imported
        lastWord = Mid(str, InStrRev(str, delim) + 1I)
        lastWord = Mid(str, str.LastIndexOf(delim) + 2I)

        ' These are safe for .NET 2.0 and higher:
        lastWord = strArr(strArr.Length - 1I)
        lastWord = strArr(strArr.GetUpperBound(0I))

        ' These require .NET 3.5 and higher:
        lastWord = (From word As String In strArr Select word).Last
        lastWord = strArr.Last
        lastWord = strArr.ElementAt(strArr.GetUpperBound(0I))
    End Sub
End Module
```